# How to remove layers that are not in visible df extent

Tags: arcpy, layers, extents, arcgis-10.3, data-frame

I am working on ArcMap 10.3 and I have a map with 50 layers in it.

I am trying to check if layers are in a data frame.

Unlike [How to check if layers in a dataframe with Arcpy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107379/how-to-check-if-layers-in-a-dataframe-with-arcpy), I want to define the area to the current data frame.

My code is:

```
import arcpy,os,sys,string
import arcpy.mapping
from arcpy import env


env.workspace = r"C:\Project"
for mxdname in arcpy.ListFiles('*.mxd'):
     print mxdname
     mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Project\\" + mxdname)
     df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
     data_frame = df
     for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"",df):
          if lyr in data_frame == False:
               arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)
               print lyr     
     mxd.save()
del  mxd
```

and I get:

```
 >>> 
Project.mxd
>>>
```

but no layers have been removed.

Comment: Your question title seems highly related to the extent of your data frame but the code in its body makes no mention of extents. I think you should edit your title so that it summarizes the code you are seeking help with.

Comment: I'm not sure, without testing, if testing whether a layer object is in a data frame object is valid syntax, but even if it is, you seem to be saying "if layer is not in data frame then remove it from that data frame" i.e. do nothing.

Comment: Crossposted - https://geonet.esri.com/message/495384

Comment: i can't crossposted a question?

Comment: @newGIS yes you can crosspost, I was just noting that it was crosposted for other users information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Extent](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z00000072000000) object supports a 'disjoint' (i.e. does not intersect) method.

Try something like:

```
for mxdname in arcpy.ListFiles('*.mxd'):

     print mxdname
     mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(os.path.join(env.workspace, mxdname))
     df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
     for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "" ,df):
          if df.extent.disjoint(lyr.getExtent()):
               arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)
               print lyr

     mxd.save()

del  mxd
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to create a polygon feature layer of the dataframe extent, then you may select features in your dataframe to see if they intersect the extent polygon.

http://anothergisblog.blogspot.com/2011/06/dataframe-object.html

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df)
# Extent Polygon
extentPolygon = arcpy.Polygon(arcpy.Array([df.extent.lowerLeft,df.extent.lowerRight, df.extent.upperRight, df.extent.upperLeft]),
df.spatialReference)
# Select all features in current extent
for lyr in layers:
   arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(lyr, "INTERSECT", extentPolygon, "", "NEW_SELECTION")
del mxd
```

Finally, for each layer you may use the Get Count (Data Management) method to see if the count is greater than zero, if so then remove the layer from the map:

```
arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)
```