# Code error - remove layer using python

Tags: arcpy, layers, remove

Continuously to [How to remove layers that are not in visible df extent](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142311/how-to-remove-layers-that-are-not-in-visible-df-extent) i try to remove layers that don't appear in the data frame with this code:

```
import arcpy,os
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"C:\Project"
for mxdname in arcpy.ListFiles('*.mxd'):
    print mxdname
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(os.path.join(env.workspace, mxdname))
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "" ,df):
        if df.extent.disjoint(lyr.getExtent()):
            arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)
            print 'removed ' ,lyr
    mxd.save()
del mxd
```

but i get an error:

```
>>> 
antiquities.mxd
ecology.mxd
land_use2  a2.mxd
removed  Bad_smell
removed  polygon_1
removed  polygon_1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/yaron.KAYAMOT/Desktop/python2.py", line 14, in <module>
if df.extent.disjoint(lyr.getExtent()):
  File "C:\Program Files     (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\arcobjects\arcobjects.py", line 144, in     disjoint
    return     convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.Disjoint(*gp_fixargs([second_geo    metry])))
ValueError: None
>>>
```

UPDATE:
i try GISGe advice in the code:

```
import arcpy,os
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"C:\Project"
for mxdname in arcpy.ListFiles('*.mxd'):
    print mxdname
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(os.path.join(env.workspace, mxdname))
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "" ,df):
        if lyr.getExtent() != None:
            if df.extent.disjoint(lyr.getExtent()):
                arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)        

    mxd.save()
del mxd
```

but no layer add been removed and i got:

```
antiquities.mxd
ecology.mxd
ta34b4.mxd
ta35_mirkamim.mxd
>>>
```

Comment: Have you got an mxd in your list that has no layers, or perhaps the data frame is not named "Layers"?

Comment: no, i have layers in all maps and all data frame named Layers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a layer without extent, like a group layer. Add a condition to verify this before comparing the extent of the data frame with the layer's:

```
 ...
 for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "" ,df):
     if lyr.getExtent() != None:
        if df.extent.disjoint(lyr.getExtent()):
            arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)
 ...
```

Comment: GISGe, am i fixed the code right in my update? because nothing happend

Comment: What about the 'land_use2  a2.mxd' mxd? It's in this mxd you had an error but it's notprinted in your new message. For the other mxds, are you sure that there are layers to be removed?

Comment: yes  i forgot to write it. now i succeed with the code to remove layers- but when i try to remove layers that their folder route are not in English i got error