# Remove layers using python- path orientation

Tags: arcpy, layers, mxd, unicode

Expanding on my previous question [Code error - remove layer using python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169551/code-error-remove-layer-using-python), i try to remove layers from mxd's (in ArcMap 10.3, python 2.7.8), that don't appear in the data frame with this code:

```
import arcpy,os
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"D:\desktop\Project"
for mxdname in arcpy.ListFiles('*.mxd'):
    print mxdname
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(os.path.join(env.workspace, mxdname))
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "" ,df):
        if lyr.getExtent() != None:
            if df.extent.disjoint(lyr.getExtent()):
                arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)
                print 'removed '+str(lyr)
    mxd.save()
del mxd
```

but i get an error:

```
>>> 
project1.mxd
removed point

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\CCleaner\yaron\shonot\software\---gis---  \tools\YARON_SCRIPTS\remove lyr that are not in df 2.py", line 19, in <module>
    print 'removed '+str(lyr) # this is optional(earase the # sign): ,'from '+str(mxdname)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1-5: ordinal not in range(128)
>>>
```

I think this error derives from the fact that one layer has different path orientation (right to left- different language from English), If i use layers with regular path orientation(English only) the code works just fine.

Comment: See is this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25103575/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-characters-in-position-0-3-ordin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem with the removing process. As the error states, you are trying to convert a unicode string to an ascii string by using `str()` function

You should only change the very last lines to fix your problem:

```
print u'Removed '+unicode(lyr)
```