# Remove layers in sub folders using python- path orientation

Tags: arcpy, mxd, data-frame, remove

Expanding on my previous question [Remove layers using python- path orientation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174891/remove-layers-using-python-path-orientation), 
i try to remove layers from mxd's (in ArcMap 10.3, Python 2.7.8), that don't appear in the layout view.

The layers located in different disk drivers and in different folders and sub folders and each layer has different path orientation (right to left- different language from English). Only the MXD's located in "D:\desktop\Project".

The data view contain two layers:

[image]

The extent of river layer is:

[image]

and the extent of land use layer is:

[image]

In the layout view i need to zoom to this area only:

[image]

and river layer don't appear in this area, although the river extent contain the land use extent inside of it. I using this code:

```
import arcpy,os
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"D:\desktop\Project"
for mxdname in arcpy.ListFiles('*.mxd'):
    print mxdname
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(os.path.join(env.workspace, mxdname))
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "" ,df):
        print str(lyr.getExtent())
        print lyr.name
        if lyr.getExtent() != None:
            if df.extent.disjoint(lyr.getExtent()):
                arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)
                print u'Removed ' + unicode(lyr) 
    mxd.save()
del mxd
```

When i run the code i get project name and all layers name, and no filtering layers is done:

```
>>> 
project.mxd
91903.0350764695 574029.485062387 200813.043872879 654364.436708682 NaN NaN NaN NaN
river
150949.479567489 608397.791172772 163831.70252934 619047.879128692 NaN NaN NaN NaN
land use
>>>
```

My target is to remove river layer from all MXD's.

Comment: I think you should put in some more `print` statements so that you can see rather than assume which code is being run.  I think `print lyr.name` on the line before `if lyr.getExtent() != None:` would be quite informative.

Comment: Try putting `print str(lyr.getExtent())` before `print lyr.name` to see whether it is `None` before applying your test.

Comment: PolyGeo, how can i solve my question?

Comment: Try putting `print str(df.extent)` before `df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]`.  That should then enable you to see and compare the values of the two rectangles that you are providing to the `disjoint` method.  You will then be able to see whether True or False is correctly being returned by `df.extent.disjoint(lyr.getExtent())`.  It is hard to pinpoint your problem because I am not clear about what you are trying to achieve.  I *think* it distils to testing whether a layer extent falls totally outside the data frame extent.

Comment: PolyGeo, i re edit my question