# Adding rasters from folder if it in the data frame extent of the map using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-10.3, data-frame, error-000368

I have 55 rasters located in "G:\desktop\Project\lyr\50k", and i try to add them to MXD file - only if the rasters extent are in the dataframe extent of the MXD file, using python code (in ArcGIS 10.3):

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r"G:\desktop\Project\lyr\50k"
for rasterFile in arcpy.ListFiles("*.jpg"):
    print rasterFile
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"G:\desktop\Project\project.mxd")
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
    dfAsFeature = arcpy.Polygon(arcpy.Array([df.extent.lowerLeft, df.extent.lowerRight, df.extent.upperRight, df.extent.upperLeft]),df.spatialReference)
    if arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(rasterFile , "INTERSECT", dfAsFeature):
        addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(rasterFile)
        arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer, "TOP")
        print 'add to map'
    mxd.save()
del mxd, addLayer
```

but i got en error and i don't understand what is the problem- i placed the rasterFlie and dfAsFeature variable in the arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management row, and got mistake:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g:\Users\yaron\Desktop\abc.py", line 9, in <module>
if arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(rasterFile , "INTERSECT", dfAsFeature):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 7359, in SelectLayerByLocation
raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000368: Invalid input data.
Failed to execute (SelectLayerByLocation).
```

I red:

[Checking if layers in dataframe using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107379/how-to-check-if-layers-in-a-dataframe-with-arcpy)

Answer (score 0):

Although we cannot see your full error message (including line number) and output from your print statement, it looks to me like you should review the [Select Layer By Location help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-location.htm#GUID-CC074F49-345A-4FEE-A1B4-D4FC92ED0E9C) because in the tool syntax of:

```
SelectLayerByLocation_management (in_layer, {overlap_type}, {select_features}, {search_distance}, {selection_type}, {invert_spatial_relationship})
```

the `in_layer` is expected to be one of:

> Feature Layer; Mosaic Layer; Raster Catalog Layer

You are providing a raster dataset instead of a raster layer so I suggest using [Make Raster Layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-raster-layer.htm) first.

Comment: how do i integrated in in my code?